# ¿Por qué sale reflejado en el ostream el incremento de una variable hecho a su referencia antes de realizarlo?

Tags: c++

¿A qué se debe este resultado inesperado?

**Código**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int n = 3;

    int &ref = n;

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << n << "-" << ref++ << std::endl;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

**Salida**

```
3
4-3
4
```

## Actualización

La versión del compilador g++ que estaba usando era la 5.4.0, aprovechando que he visto la web wandbox en otra pregunta he probado otras versiones y a partir de la versión 7.1.0 el resultado ya es el esperado.

¿Se podría tomar como un bug de una versión anterior del compilador? No se si se podría calificar de cuasi-respuesta, aunque me gustaría saber exactamente que pasaba y que cambiaron, si alguien lo sabe, por curiosidad más que nada, de todas formas seguiré investigando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿A qué se debe este resultado inesperado?

El resultado no es inesperado para nada.

Los post-incrementos deben ser evaluados antes del siguiente punto de secuencia. ¿Y qué es un punto de secuencia? El más habitual es el punto y coma que marca el final de la línea.

Es decir, el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int var = 0;
std::cout << var++ << var++;
```

Perfectamente puede devolver alguno de los siguientes resultados:

```
00
01
10
```

¿Por qué? Pues simplemente porque ambos incrementos se encuentran en la misma secuencia y el compilador es libre para elegir el orden en el que ejecuta las operaciones. Así, para el caso que ocupa tu pregunta, la línea:

```
std::cout << n << "-" << ref++ << std::endl;
```

Podría compilarse de forma equivalente a algunos de estos ejemplos:

- El incremento se evalua al final

  ```
  std::cout << n << "-" << ref;
  ref++;
  ```
- Se procesa `ref`, se evalua el incremento y después se procesa `n`:

  int temp = ref;
  ref++;
  std::cout << n << "-" << temp;

Así, la instrucción podría imprimir, en principio, dos posibles resultados:

3-3
   4-3

Si no quieres obtener resultados inesperados procura no actualizar y utilizar la misma variable entre dos puntos de secuencia. Es más seguro hacer esto:

```
std::cout << n << "-" << ref << std::endl;
ref++;
```

Ya que así el incremento se encuentra en un punto de secuencia diferente y el resultado de la ejecución será siempre el mismo.

Piensa que, sobre el papel, C++ se ha diseñado pensando en la eficiencia, luego se le deja mucho margen al compilador para decidir sobre la mejor manera de optimizar el código... cuidado con hacer cosas raras.